# Не получается сделать проверку на четность и чтоб значение не было равно 0

Tags: c#

Нужно чтобы число при этом было чётное и не равно 0, в else не хочу выносить.Но почему то 0 пишет как чётное число, а нужно чтоб при вводе 0 не писалось

```
static int[] Set_Mass(int value,int x)
    {
    
        if(x > value - 1) return null;
        
        int[]arr = new int[value];
        Console.Write($"[{x + 1}] = ");
        arr[x] = Console.Read();
        if((arr[x] % 2) == 0 && arr[x] != 0)Console.WriteLine(" Четное число");
        else Console.WriteLine();
        
        
        
        
            
        Set_Mass(value,++x);
        
        
        return arr;
    
    
    
    }
```

Comment: Опечатка, `Console.Read();` замените на `int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`. И почитайте документацию по методу `Read()`, он считывает не число с консоли, а символ.

Comment: Та к сожалению нет, специально поставил, чтоб после ввода не переходило на новую строку если число чётное, иначе переход с помощью writeline

Comment: Вы выведите в консоль это число и убедитесь, что там действительно не 0. Попробуйте так `= Console.Read() - '0'`

Comment: Да это помогло) И заодним понял что я не могу вводить числа, только символы, когда попытался ввести 10.Просто искал способ ввода без перехода на новую строку, и наткнулся на этот метод. А скажите пж Console. Read() - '0' что это значит или где про это почитать.

Comment: Read считывает код символа, так как коды символов цифр идут в таблице ASCII по порядку, чтобы из кода символа '0' получить 0, надо просто сделать этл вычитание. Единица следующая, и так далее.

Comment: вы можете после `Console.ReadLine()` вернуть вручную курсор на предыдущую строку через `Console.SetCursorPosition(..., ...)`. По Y-ку берёте текущую позицию - 1, а по X-су можно позицию посчитать (сложить длину выведенного вами текста + длину введённого)

Comment: @aepot смотрите у нас 127 символов в ascii, символ '0' под кодом 48. Т. е если мы считаем символ с консоли и пр своим переменной то присвоится число 48.А чтобы число 48 не присвоилось, а присвоилось введенное нами число мы от 48 отнимаем 48 и получаем 0,правильно?

Comment: Ну это просто должно быть, да

Comment: @aepot Благодарю, как всегда лучший 